# How to seconds convert to day,hours and seconds in moment.js with reactjs and typescript

Tags: reactjs, typescript, momentjs

**I want this :** i have seconds. if i give seconds to moment function i  want this values day, hours, seconds.

I had used moment.js and i get to output log also but i could not get particular key values.

Installed package :

```
"moment": "^2.24.0"
```

Usage:

```
import moment from 'moment';

const value: number = 172200;
const convertType: any = moment.duration(value, 'seconds');
console.log('convertType:', convertType);
```

Log output:

```
convertType:
Duration {
_data:  { days: 1 ,hours: 23, milliseconds: 0, minutes: 50, months: 0
          seconds: 0, years: 0 }
_days: 0
_isValid: true
_locale: Locale {...}
_milliseconds: 172200000
_months: 0
}
```

how do i get **_data** values from **Duration {}**.

```
_data: {days: 1 ,hours: 23, milliseconds: 0, minutes: 50, months: 0
      seconds: 0, years: 0}
```

i had tried this way but i get undefined

```
console.log('output:', convertType.Duration);
```

Comment: What's the problem with `any._data`, this is working fine for me

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This works well [here](http://jsfiddle.net/vurf4z8x/):

```
const value=172200;
const any=moment.duration(value, 'seconds');
const data=any._data
console.log(`Duration: ${data.years} Years, ${data.months} Months, ${data.days} Days, ${data.hours} Hours, ${data.minutes} Minutes, ${data.seconds} Seconds, ${data.milliseconds} Milliseconds   `)
```